# JavaScript - Redirect to a new webpage without a protocol

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I want to redirect to a new URL, but it cannot use a protocol, as it needs to redirect to an ftp server (at `IP:21`, not `ftp://IP`) so far, I have this code:

```
<script>location.href = \"$FTP\";</script>
```

Don't mind the `$FTP`, it's because I did some PHP trickery to get the IP and add the port on.

Currently, this code tries to navigate to a file called `IP:21` on the server, how can I get it to redirect instead of this?

Comment: You can't redirect to an FTP server. Chrome dropped support for FTP servers in version 88, Firefox dropped it in version 90.

Comment: Not in the browser, using ftp then open ftp.*domain*.com 443.

Comment: Browsers can't run shell commands.

Comment: I'm saying in the terminal, completely outside of the browser.

Comment: Instead of a script that redirects, display a web page that tells the user what command to run in the terminal.

Comment: They can copy and paste the command from the page to the terminal.

Comment: True, that would work I guess, it's better than nothing.